# How to get the text from span using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get the text from the span. I tried but I am not getting the text. Here is my code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


    $("#cd").click(function(){

        var msg = $("#cdmsg").text();
        alert(msg);

    });

});

</script>



<div id="cd">Cash On Delivery</div>

<div class="content">
    <span id="cdmsg">Some Text Bla Bla Bla</span>
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: I think you are not included jQuery library

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Uf5B3/1/ - any error in console

Comment: i already included that. 
`<script src="Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: the script should be after the jquery library icluded eg: `<script src="Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script> //your script </script>`

Comment: @UnknownUser thats what I did. but still not working.

Comment: @FazilMir : then the problem lies in the path of the library `src="Js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"`

Comment: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` include jQuery CDN instead and try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in your given jquery.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a6NJk/695/)

there will be only one reason that you did not include jquery library.
 make sure you have included it.
try like this to check that jquery is loaded:

```
 if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
   alert("not loaded jquery!");
  }
```

Comment: jquery library is already included and other functions are working fine in my script but just this function is not working ?

Comment: then it seems that you have something wrong in your html or full js code. can you add full js and html in your question?

Comment: Awlad yeah you are right there was an error in my full jquery script. I rectified it, thanks. now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's something wrong with the path of your jQuery, try to use:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also, another reason is probably because you've multiple ids with name `cdmsg`. Try to change your `id` to class then use:

```
$(".cdmsg").click(function(){
    var msg = $(this).text();
    alert(msg);
});
```